# How to keep menus up as persistant toolboxes

Tags: interface, add-on, shortcut

Maya 2017 had a feature where you could "tear off" any program menu, and it then acts as a persistant little window that made using tools easier.

Is there any way to get the same fuctionality in Blender? I'm having trouble finding exactly what I'm looking for.

This following part is answered. [ Shift + A ] > [ S ] Sounds like an elegant enough shortcut for me to use for this specific purpose

> My current need is in geometry nodes. I want have the "add nodes" menu
> open in a window instead of needing to right click and fiddle through
> menus.

Comment: Just a stupid question: What would be the advantage compared to the key combination Shift+A? That would just waste screen space, wouldn't it?

Comment: Shift + A and then you could press S and type the name of the action that you need

Comment: This isn't possible in Blender, it was explicitely designed that way by the developers : No overlapping panels

Comment: The _Add_ menu has a lot of subsections - do you want them all to be expanded? What a mess... and if you just have the top menu I could imagine it's not much easier to find everything from there if you don't know exactly where to look. Instead of the _Add_ menu you could also press `F3` and start typing what you are looking for, the search will narrow down the results the more you type in. Nodes you need more often you could right-click and either add them to the _Quick Favourites_ or assign a shortcut to them.

Comment: Seems I was a bit bored in my lunch break, so I just looked through the menu... there are 227 nodes in my current version 3.5.1 that can be added (actually just 225 because _Group Input_ and _Group Output_ are both twice in there), and you want a permanent panel showing them all so you don't have to "fiddle through menus"?

Comment: Sounds like the answer is no. 
For the way my brain works, having a scrollable list of the nodes that could be dragged and dropped would help me think when I'm working. 
However, thanks for the tips about [ Shift+A ] > [ S ] I'll try and make that a habit
Cheers, folks!